# The fastest way to copy a huge dataset to server in SAS

Tags: sql-server, sas, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

### **Edited on Oct 21th**

**Background**

Raw datasets (changed everday) stored on a MS-SQL based server: `Sourcelib.RAW` and a `LOCAL` excel file (remained `unchanged`).

I need to refresh a dataset `WANT`locates in `Targerlib`. Currently I have SQL codes perform such task in 2-3 minutes. But I want to know if SAS can do the same thing while the processing time won't increase much.

1. `work.IMP` is around 6M records and around 50 bytes per record.
2. The ideal method should be very efficient because as time goes by, the size of raw datasets on the server would be incrediblely huge.
3. The target file `CANNOT` be establied at one time and then append new data to it everyday. Because there maybe (even very unlikely) changes in previous data.

As per @Joe, I should allow the target file to just be updated, using `proc compare`, or `update` in `data step`. Here's a related question I posted [How to use proc compare to update dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420777/how-to-use-proc-compare-to-update-dataset)

4. Still more than 10GB free space on the sever, which is enough. Avaiable memory in my pc is around 3.5GB (not sure if it matters)
5. Due to the architecture of server, it's very efficient to do it in MS-SQL. But I REALLY want to know if SAS can deal with this (when the server is not so `"compatible"`)

**Process**

1. First I import the data from excel file and then `subset&tranpose` it to be `work.IMP`. For some reasons, this file can only be created in this way everday. It `CANNOT` be store in the server.
2. Then perform outer join for `work.IMP` and one raw dataset `Sourcelib.RAW1` to get `work.HAVE1`. Please note that `work.IMP` is sorted but `Sourcelib.RAW1` is unsorted. The outer join is only to (with some criteria) determine each data records.

`i.e. case when a.COL1 is '' then b.COL1 else a.COL1 end as COL1`

You can consider this process is to adjust `Sourcelib.RAW1` by using `work.IMP`.

PS1: @sparc_spread suggests to do the import procedure directly to the server. But it won't have any benefit than do it in `LOCAL`. And a `hash object` here doesn't help either.

3. Then I subset another raw datasets `Sourcelib.RAW2` to `work.temp`, and then `sort` it to be `work.HAVE2`. (The data in `Sourcelib.RAW2` is mostly not in order.)
4. I concatenate `work.HAVE1`, `work.HAVE2` by using `proc append` (because both two tables are huge) to be `work.HAVE`

PS2: The sorting in `step3` is to avoid sorting at the end of `step4`. Actually the data `Targerlib.WANT` doesn't have to be in order. But it's better to be so.

5. At the very end, I copy `work.HAVE` to server `Targetlib.HAVE`.

I did most of the thing in `WORK`, which only took me few minutes. But `step5` could take me half an hour to finish the copy.

As per @Joe, this may mainly due to something related to network transit. `I.E` minmize the network transit

**Question**

Any way to improve `step5`? Or any modification of the whole process will improve the performance?

Comment: A) It looks like you start with `work.IMP`, then split it into two datasets, then re-concatenate those into one. If there's some way this could be avoided, that would be great - can you tell me more about the manipulation you do in step 2 B) Are you running on Windows or Linux?  What is the hardware situation for the libraries (are they on separate disks, are those disks some kind of RAID, what this the setup for your utility library (UTILLOC), etc.)?

Comment: Have you looked into bulk loading options if you're moving it across servers?

Comment: Are the 2 systems of the same architecture?  IE both Windows?

Comment: @sparc_spread not really split it into two. I have edited my question with more details in manipulation.

Comment: @Reese I used the default setting. How can I optimize this?

Comment: @DomPazz You mean the SQL server and SAS server? My pc is windows ... I don't know much about it.

Comment: Do `sourcelib.raw` and `sourcelib.raw2` begin as text files or as SAS datasets?  Please also let me know re my questions on disk, particularly if `targetlib` and `work` are on the same or different disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of thoughts.

First off, assuming this is a SAS dataset and not a SQL database or something else, `options compress=binary;` is a good idea assuming this is mostly numeric (and `options compress=character;` if not).  Either will reduce the physical size of the dataset significantly in most cases.

Second, 300MB is not very much in the scheme of things.  My network would write that in less than a minute.  What the conditions of your network are may drive some of the other choices you make; if the single slow point is simply copying data across it, for example, then you need to figure out how to reduce that at the cost of anything else you do.

Assuming you don't change anything else, I would recommend writing `have1` directly to the network as `have`, and then append `have2` to it.  IE, whatever step creates `have1`, have that directly write to the network.  This includes `sort` steps, note: so if you create it then sort it, create it locally and sort it with `out=` the network library.  This reduces the total amount of writing done (as you don't write a useless copy of `have1` to your local drive).  This helps if writing locally is a relevant cost to your total process, but won't help if it's almost entirely network congestion.

Copying files with the OS's copy is almost always superior to any other method of copying, so if network congestion is the only factor you care about, you may want to make it locally (in WORK or in a local but constant directory, like `C:\temp\` or similar) and then have the last step of your process be executing `copy c:\temp\have.sas7bdat \\networklocation\whereitgoes\`.  This will usually outperform SAS methods for same, as it can take advantage of efficient techniques.

`PROC COPY` is another option to get around network congestion; it's probably faster than `PROC APPEND` (if the local write-out is negligible, as it would be for me for <1 GB data), and has the advantage that it's a bit safer in case something happens during the transport.  (Append should be fine also, but with COPY you know for sure nothing was changed from yesterday's file.)

Finally, you may want to figure out some way to allow the target file to just be updated.  This isn't all that hard to do in most cases.  One example would be to keep a copy of yesterday's file, do a `PROC COMPARE` to today's file, and then include in the update file every record that is changed (regardless of what the change is).  Then delete any matching old records from the target file and append the new records.  This is very fast comparatively in terms of total records sent over the network, so saves a lot of time overall if network congestion is the main issue (but takes more CPU time to do the PROC COMPARE).

Comment: for the 4th point, I did that all in WORK. So it's alreadly local? For the 5th point, should I append `HAVE2` in WORK to `HAVE` in the network, or append `HAVE2` in network (I put it to network in previous step) to `HAVE` in the network? For the 3rd point, I have edited my question with more details, could you take a look to see if that's what you recommend? For the `compress` option, I will try it out. Thanks.

Comment: How could `proc compare` do the work? Doesn't it simply return the non-matching records information?

Comment: Exactly.  You use it to identify non-identical records, and only those records are loaded.  You can instruct it to return only the records from the COMPARE dataset and only those that are different, which would be your to-be-loaded set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PROC APPEND` to efficiently create a new dataset, not just append to an existing - thus you can use that to basically combines steps 3 and 4 into this:

```
/* To fulfill requirement 4, delete existing Targetlib.HAVE */
PROC DELETE LIBRARY="Targetlib" DATA="HAVE"; 
RUN;

/* Targetlib.HAVE does not yet exist, the first APPEND will create it */
PROC APPEND BASE="Targetlib.HAVE" DATA="work.HAVE1";
RUN;

PROC APPEND BASE="Targetlib.HAVE" DATA="work.HAVE2";
RUN;
```

That should save at least some time, but that still doesn't solve all your problems... I have some additional questions I have put in comments to the question and will alter this answer as much as I can based on them.

---

### Update 1

Here is a way to do the left join and the concatenation in one step and write the results immediately to `targetlib`.  I cannot guarantee this will be faster but it is worth a try.  I used `key` and `val` as field names, replace as you see fit.

```
PROC SQL _METHOD;
    CREATE TABLE targetlib.HAVE
    AS
    SELECT
        a.key ,
        CASE WHEN MISSING (a.val) THEN b.val ELSE a.val END AS val  
    FROM
        Sourcelib.RAW1 AS a
    LEFT JOIN
        IMP AS b
        ON
            a.key = b.key
    UNION
    SELECT
        c.*
    FROM
        Sourcelib.RAW2 AS c
    ORDER BY
        key
;
QUIT;
RUN;
```

The `_METHOD` is a sparsely documented SAS feature that will print the query plan, see [this link](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/200-2013.pdf). This may give you more insight. Also, I am assuming that `IMP` was already imported from the Excel, and that it is in `WORK`.  Experiment to see whether importing it to `targetlib` and replacing `IMP as b` with `targetlib.IMP as b` is any faster here.

Since you are on Windows, experiment with the data option `SGIO=YES` after dataset names:  e.g. `Sourcelib.RAW1 AS a` becomes `Sourcelib.RAW1 (SGIO=YES) AS a`. For more info on Windows SGIO and SAS, see [this link](http://www.biginfoanalysis.com/sas-sgio-achieve-better-io-throughput/) and [this older but more comprehensive one](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/IOthruSGIO.pdf).

An approach that *might* be more efficient would be to avoid the join and use a hash object instead:  good documentation for hash object [can be found here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/67885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1b4cbtmb049xtn1vh9x4waiioz4.htm) and [a good tip sheet is here](http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/datastep/dot/hash-tip-sheet.pdf).  It's not clear whether this would be faster - `imp` has 6m records, but at 50 bytes per record, that's about 300 MB, which does fit into your RAM.  The performance of a hash table with that many entries would depend a lot on SAS's hash algorithm.  Anyway, here is the code using a hash object. In it, we assume that in the `IMP` dataset, the `val` field has been renamed to `val2`.

```
DATA targetlib.HAVE (DROP = rc val2);
    LENGTH val2 8. ;

    IF (_N_ = 1) THEN DO;
        DECLARE HASH h (DATASET: "IMP") ;
        h.DEFINEKEY ('key');
        h.DEFINEDATA ('val2');
        h.DEFINEDONE ();
    END;

    SET 
        sourcelib.RAW1
        sourcelib.RAW2
    ;

    IF MISSING (val) THEN DO;
        rc = h.find();
        IF (rc = 0) THEN DO;
            val = val2;
        END;
    END;
RUN;
PROC SORT DATA = targetlib.HAVE ; BY KEY ; RUN ;
```

Try it and see if it is any faster. Once again, experiment with the location of `IMP`, using `SGIO`, etc. That `PROC SORT` at the end could be expensive; if the only reason you were sorting before was because of joining, then skip it.

In general, your approach to SAS should be to do as little I/O as possible, and find ways of combining multiple actions into a single write from a `PROC` or `DATA` step.

---

Comment: the `proc append` will avoid reading the records from `data=`. In your method above, the `Targetlib.HAVE` was set to empty first, then append two large datasets `HAVE1`,`HAVE2`. So we still need to read all records from those large datasets?

Comment: Yes, this was just to skip one of your original steps.  However I am working on something new, should be posting soon... see questions in comments on original post.

Comment: `WARNING 30-12: SAS option SGIO is valid only at startup of the SAS System. The SAS option is ignored.`

Comment: The error message is misleading. It means that the dataset is too small to use SGIO. For more info see (http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/Flexibility_by_Design.pdf) and (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/67279/PDF/default/hostwin.pdf).

Comment: The server is kind of sql-based. I have tried every way to optimize the code but the performance is still very bad.(But ms-sql can do this in less than 2 minutes). I guess it's something related to the architecture of the server that mattets.

Comment: If you can do it faster in MS-SQL, I would stick with that.