# How to use proc compare to update dataset

Tags: compare, sas

I want to use `proc compare` to update dataset on a daily basis.

`work.HAVE1`

```
Date        Key Var1 Var2 
01Aug2013   K1   a    2
01Aug2013   K2   a    3
02Aug2013   K1   b    4
```

`work.HAVE2`

```
Date        Key Var1 Var2 
01Aug2013   K1   a    3
01Aug2013   K2   a    3
02Aug2013   K1   b    4
03Aug2013   K2   c    1
```

`Date` and `Key` are uniquely determine one record.
How can I use the above two tables to construct the following

`work.WANT`

```
Date        Key Var1 Var2 
01Aug2013   K1   a    3
01Aug2013   K2   a    3
02Aug2013   K1   b    4
03Aug2013   K2   c    1
```

I don't want to delete the previous data and then rebuild it. I want to `modify` it via append new records at the bottom and adjust the values in `VAR1` or `VAR2`. 
I'm struggling with `proc compare` but it just doesn't return what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
proc compare base=work.HAVE1 compare=work.HAVE2 out=WORK.DIFF outnoequal outcomp;
id Date Key;
run;
```

This will give you new and changed (unequal records) in single dataset WORK.DIFF. You'll have to distinguish new vs changed yourself.

However, what you want to achieve is actually a `MERGE` - inserts new, overwrites existing, though maybe due to performance reasons etc. you don't want to re-create the full table.

```
data work.WANT;
    merge work.HAVE1 work.HAVE2;
    by Date Key;
run;
```

Edit1:

```
/* outdiff option will produce records with _type_ = 'DIF' for matched keys */
proc compare base=work.HAVE1 compare=work.HAVE2 out=WORK.RESULT outnoequal outcomp outdiff;
id Date Key;
run;


data WORK.DIFF_KEYS;  /* keys of changed records */
    set WORK.RESULT;
    where _type_ = 'DIF';
    keep Date Key;
run;

/* split NEW and CHANGED */
data
    WORK.NEW
    WORK.CHANGED
;
 merge
      WORK.RESULT (where=( _type_ ne 'DIF'));
        WORK.DIFF_KEYS (in = d)
    ;
  by Date Key;
  if d then output WORK.CHANGED;
  else output WORK.NEW;
run;
```

Edit2:

Now you can just `APPEND` the WORK.NEW to target table.

For WORK.CHANGED - either use `MODIFY` or `UPDATE` statement to update the records.
Depending on the size of the changes, you can also think about `PROC SQL; DELETE` to delete old records and `PROC APPEND` to add new values.

Comment: Forgot to mention. `Have1` is actually on the server while `Have2` is local. `Merge` may need more processing time for large datasets?

Comment: @GMTG This works better when you're able to keep a 'local' copy of `HAVE1`, or at least those parts of `HAVE1` that might change.  If you're unable to keep a copy of the master dataset on a local drive, this may not benefit you all that much (as you end up with a lot of network transit anyway).

Comment: @vasja For `new`, I can just append it. For `changed`,  I need one more `merge` (somthing like `if a and if not b`)?

Comment: @Joe Why it works better when a local copy of previous data exists? If so, at the end of the day I will need to pass all the data to the server.

Comment: It works better because you it saves a network transit.  If `have1` has a local copy, then the only data that needs to transit is the difference (you do have to update `have1` twice, once updating local and once updating the network, but hopefully that's not expensive).  If `have1` is on the network only, then you have to pull all of `have1` back, compare, then push the updates, ending up pushing much or all of the same data as just replacing the network copy in total.

Answer (score 0):

All a PROC COMPARE will do will tell you the differences between 2 datasets.  To achieve your goal you need to use an UPDATE statement in a data step.  This way, values in HAVE1 are updated with HAVE2 where the date and key match, or a new record inserted if there are no matches.

```
data have1;
input Date :date9. Key $ Var1 $ Var2;
format date date9.;
datalines;
01Aug2013   K1   a    2
01Aug2013   K2   a    3
02Aug2013   K1   b    4
;
run;

data have2;
input Date :date9. Key $ Var1 $ Var2;
format date date9.;
datalines;
01Aug2013   K1   a    3
01Aug2013   K2   a    3
02Aug2013   K1   b    4
03Aug2013   K2   c    1
;
run;

data want;
update have1 have2;
by date key;
run;
```

Comment: `have1` is on the network. `have2` is local. Using a data step like this with large data will lead to unacceptable performance?

Comment: Keith, this is linked to an earlier question; the point here is to be able to perform an update with minimal network transit (hence the proc compare to identify records to update).

Comment: In which case, how about creating an index on HAVE1, then using MODIFY to update it with HAVE2?  I haven't time to write the code now, but have a look at this article, in particular MODIFY with KEY= Option and  SET statement. http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/264-31.pdf